# If statement vs function blocks for var keywords

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, scope

My question is why is a variable (when using var keyword) accessible outside the if statement block, but not outside the function block?  Consider this code:

```
let age = 30;

if (true){
    let age = 40
    console.log('inside', age)  //logs inside, 40//
    var name = 'shaun'
}

console.log('outside if loop', age, name) //logs outside if loop, 30, shaun //

function test (){
    var xyz = 'ashley';
    console.log(xyz)

}
test ()

console.log('outside function', xyz) //throws an error//
```

Thank you for your time.  Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

Because of the current context of execution. The context in which values and expressions are "visible" or can be referenced. If a variable or other expression is not "in the current scope," then it is unavailable for use. Scopes can also be layered in a hierarchy, so that child scopes have access to parent scopes, but not vice versa.

A function serves as a closure in JavaScript, and thus creates a scope, so that (for example) a variable defined exclusively within the function cannot be accessed from outside the function or within other functions.

Also ES6 does have block scope for variable definitions with the `let` and `const` keywords but not with `var`.

[Here is an article on Wikipedia about Scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).

Comment: So the scope for for-loops or if-statements is considered different than the scope for functions?  I thought they were all local scopes, and hence should not be accessible globally?  But in my example it is clear that if-statement's local variable name is accessible outside of the statement, but the function variable is not.

Comment: JavaScript has no "block scope", it only has function scope - so variables declared inside an if statement (or any conditional block) are "hoisted" to the outer scope.

Comment: Aaaah!!! This clears it for me.  Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: _'JavaScript has no "block scope"'_ - `let` and `const` want to have a word...

Comment: Maybe I need to learn more, you're right, seems like there was a scope change after ECMAScript 2015 (6th edition). I edited the answer.